# Estimates for Montel's theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: analysis, several-complex-variables

As I'm beginning to study the theory of several complex variables, a lot of the early proofs that I've seen from the textbooks I'm using (Range's Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables, for example) tend to be very cursory because it is claimed that such proofs are easy generalisations of the theory from one variable. I personally don't really like such sketch proofs, so have tried my best to flesh them out in as much detail as possible. The result I'm currently trying to prove is essentially Montel's theorem, and the way that I want to do it is by adapting the proof I know in one variable. This involves showing that if my sequence $(f_j)$ of holomorphic functions is uniformly bounded on every compact subset of a region $D$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then it is equicontinuous on every compact subset of $D$, and then by Arzela-Ascoli and a diagonalisation argument, I should be able to extract a compactly convergent subsequence.

The equicontinuity step is what is bothering me. By Cauchy's integral formula, I want to be able to estimate $|f_j(z) - f_j(w)|$ to as small as my liking for every $j$ and for every $z, w$ in a given compact set with $|z - w| < r$. In one variable, this is quite straightforward by taking a slightly smaller disc in the compact set, so that we'd be able to bound
$$\left|\frac{1}{\zeta - z} - \frac{1}{\zeta - w}\right| = \frac{|z - w|}{|\zeta - z||\zeta - w|}$$
to our liking, where $\zeta$ lies on the boundary of the larger disc. But for $n$-dimensions, I get something like
$$\left|\frac{1}{\prod_{j = 1}^n (\zeta_j - z_j)} - \frac{1}{\prod_{j = 1}^n (\zeta_j - w_j)}\right|,$$
where $\zeta = (\zeta_1, \dots, \zeta_n)$ lies on the distinguished boundary of a polydisc.

**My question is how can we perform a similar type of bound in higher dimensions?** Cross multiplying the terms do not cancel down to something as nice as $|z - w|$ in one variable anymore, so I'm struggling to see how I can choose an $r > 0$ so that $|z - w| < r$ implies the above is as small as we want.

Comment: Can't you just view this as a continuous function on a compactum which implies that it is uniformly continuous? Or do you need some specific rate for the error?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven well I originally did try to view it that way (and maybe I'm just getting confused by it all), but I thought that there might be some annoying problems when you'd want to go from a polydisc to an arbitrary compact set?

Comment: Maybe it becomes easier if you spell out the precise statement you want to prove, i.e. what is fixed, where the elements live and what type of estimates you want. I would guess that using the continuous function $$ g(\xi, z)= \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^n (\xi_j-z_j)} $$ on suitable (compact) domains might do the trick, as you are looking to bound $\vert g(\xi, z)-g(\xi, w) \vert$ and $\vert (\xi,z) - (\xi,w)\vert=\vert z-w\vert$. Thus, uniform continuity of $g$ would solve your problem.

Comment: I suspect that you're right @SeverinSchraven, thanks for the advice! So if you'd bear with me, I'd like to show that if $(f_j)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions on $D$ that is uniformly bounded by $M > 0$, then it is equicontinuous on every compact subset of $D$. This means that for any $K$ compact and $\epsilon > 0$, there is $r > 0$ such that whenever $z, w \in K$ satisfies $|z - w| < r$, then $|f_j(z) - f_j(w)| < \epsilon$ for all $j$. I guess the strategy to do this would be to first take a polydisc $P$ centred at some point $a \in K$ and use the Cauchy integral formula...

Comment: ... to get the estimate $$|f_j(z) - f_j(w)| \leq \frac{M}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{b_0 P} |g(\xi, z) - g(\xi, w)| |d\xi|$$ for any $z, w \in P$. Would you then choose to take $z, w$ in a smaller polydisc $P'$ so that instead of $g$ being defined on $b_0 P \times P$, it's now defined on $b_0 P \times \overline{P'}$? This would then allow us to use uniform continuity right?

Comment: Yes, that looks about right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151196/discussion-between-maths-matador-and-severin-schraven).

Comment: It seems that you understand how to address all your concerns. It would be nice if you could write it up as an answer such that the next person does not need to go through all the comments in the chat.